# Calculate position vector of a particle in given force field

Tags: classical-mechanics, electric-fields, vector-fields

Suppose I have a force field in XY plane as

```
f(x,y) = yî - xĵ
```

Suppose a point object of 1kg is put at position (1,0) in this field at t=0 with zero initial velocity.
Can we calculate its position vector r(t) at any time t?

Note: this is a self made question and might be a wrong question (although I don't think so). In general I wanted to know how to calculate position vector with time in any force field or is it unsolvable.

Comment: Have you tried writing the equations of motion and solving them?

Comment: i tried integrating vdv = adx. But couldn't proceed from there

Comment: If it’s an arbitrary force field not tied to any real field,  it’s hard to really solve the problem. (forces are usually related to fields via some term, e.g. electric force is proportional to electric field by a factor of charge). But assuming you know this relationship, you can draw the forces from the field then use Newton’s equation to solve from acceleration into position by integrating twice.